# How to deal with optionals fields in Logstash/ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a problem when i try to import the following XML file in ElasticSearch with Logstash:

```
<test>
<param name="param1" raw="0x01">
<param name="param2" raw="0x02" eng="2">
<param name="param3" raw="0x03" eng="3">
</test>
```

My Logstash conf file is the following (extract):

```
xml {
    store_xml => false
    source => "message"
    xpath => [
        "/test/param/@name", "name",
        "/test/param/@raw", "raw",
        "/test/param/@eng", "eng"
    ]
}
```

After running Logstash, the ElasticSearch database contains:

```
"name": [
      "param1",
      "param2",
      "param3",
    ],
"raw": [
      "0x01",
      "0x02",
      "0x02",
    ],
"eng": [
      2,
      3,
    ],
```

I want this:

```
...
"eng": [
      null,
      2,
      3,
    ],
```

How can i force a null (or None or NaN) value in a non existing field ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Some interesting information here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html but i do not know how to adapt it to my case...

Comment: Are you able to modify input XML somehow?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, i do not have any control on this input interface (coming from another sub-system).

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the field if it does not exist, try the following (place it after the xml filter) :

```
  if ![eng] {
    mutate { add_field => { "eng" => "None" } }
  }
```

[Mutate filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html)

Comment: Thanks, but not working because "eng" is not empty at the end of the xml filter (it is equal to [2, 3]).

Comment: How about the [suppress_empty] option (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-filters-xml.html#plugins-filters-xml-suppress_empty)

Comment: Try with 'suppress_empty => false', nothing change... :(